# android gridlayout row and column not match the result

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

I want to create a `GridLayout`

Here is my setting from server:

```
 items.add(listOf(4, 3, 0, 0)) -> start at x: 0 - y:0 expand horizontal : 4, vertical 3
 items.add(listOf(1, 1, 0, 3)) -> start at x: 0 - y:3 expand horizontal : 1, vertical 1
 items.add(listOf(1, 1, 1, 3)) -> start at x: 1 - y:3 expand horizontal : 1, vertical 1
 items.add(listOf(1, 1, 2, 3)) -> start at x: 2 - y:3 expand horizontal : 1, vertical 1
 items.add(listOf(1, 1, 3, 3)) -> start at x: 3 - y:3 expand horizontal : 1, vertical 1
```

And here is my code to draw the table:

```
private fun populateTable(){
        val items = AppUtil.getListItemsForGroupLayout(layoutCode)
        val totalRows = AppUtil.getRowOrColumns(layoutCode) -> 4 rows
        val totalCols = AppUtil.getRowOrColumns(layoutCode) -> 4 columns

        tableView.columnCount = totalCols
        tableView.rowCount = totalRows

        items.forEach {
            val params = GridLayout.LayoutParams()
            params.width = 0
            params.height = 0

            params.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(it[3], it[1].toFloat())
            params.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(it[2], it[0].toFloat())

            val view = TextView(this@CallScreen)
            view.text = "${it[3]} - ${it[2]} - ${it[1]} - ${it[0]}"
            view.setBackgroundColor(Int.randomColor())
            view.layoutParams = params
            tableView.addView(view)
        }
    }
```

But the result is not the same:

[image]

Can someone tech me the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>    params.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(it[3], it[1].toFloat())
>    params.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(it[2], it[0].toFloat())
> ```

Here you are using [this version](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout#spec(int,%20float)) that provides only the start & weight values.

Looking into [other overloaded versions of `GridLayout.spec`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.Spec), there is another parameter (`size`) that also controls this behavior as by looking into the [GridLayout source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/GridLayout.java), all these overloaded methods call the private constructor:

```
    private Spec(boolean startDefined, int start, int size, Alignment alignment, float weight) {
        this(startDefined, new Interval(start, start + size), alignment, weight);
    }
```

**Solution:**

To fix this we need to use the `size` parameter by using [this overloaded version](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout#spec(int,%20int,%20float)) in setting the `params.columnSpec`:

So, in your code replace:

```
params.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(it[2], it[0].toFloat())
```

With:

```
params.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(it[2], it[0], 1f)
```

Preview:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think these two lines do what you want:

```kotlin
   params.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(it[3], it[1].toFloat())
   params.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(it[2], it[0].toFloat())
```

According to your comments, `it[0]` contains **colspan** and `it[1]` contains **rowspan**, but after converting them to *float*, an overload [spec(int start, float weight)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout#spec(int,%20float)) is called, which takes *weight factor* as second argument and size (colspan or rowspan) is 1.

Perhaps overload [spec(int start, int size, float weight)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout#spec(int,%20int,%20float)) will be more appropriate:

```kotlin
   params.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(it[3], it[1], it[1].toFloat())
   params.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(it[2], it[0], it[0].toFloat())
```

Comment: i tried your code but still not working, i only see the biggest view

Comment: @famfamfam try to clean up layout with `tableView.removeAllViews()` before populateTable() call.